# TimeSpan average

Tags: c#, timespan

I have code like this were I am repeatedly doing something and I want to get the avergae time it takes to complete that task.

```
        List<TimeSpan> TimeDisplay = new List<TimeSpan>();

        while(some condition)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                  sw.Start();
            TimeSpan temp;


            //DO SOMETHING\\

            sw.Stop();
            temp = sw.Elapsed
            TimeDisplay.Add(temp);

        }

        TimeSpan timeaverage = TimeDisplay.Average;

        System.Console.Writeline("{0}", timeaverage);
```

But I get an error on the second to last line saying I can't convert method group 'Average' to 'System.TimeSPan'

Comment: From what @Luis answered: `TimeSpan timeaverage = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeDisplay.Average(i=>i.TotalMilliseconds));`

Comment: I suspect you would be better off with a `Stopwatch`, if you tasks do not run parallelly : use Start at the beginning of each task, and Stop at the end. You will have the total time with a good accuracy. You just need to divide it by the number of tasks afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
TimeSpan timeaverage = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeDisplay.Average(i=>i.TotalMilliseconds));
```

Comment: Need to feed it back to a `TimeSpan`: `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(...)`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes, I changed it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan timeaverage = TimeSpan.FromTicks(Convert.ToInt64(TimeDisplay.Average(ts => ts.Ticks)));
```